# Most auspicious number of "dunks" in Mikve according to Kabbalah

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, mikvah-ritual-bath, practical-kabbalah

I recently had wonderful experiences bathing in Mikve in Tzfat--most particularly Mikvah HaAri. I was given basic, general guidelines to bathing there, and my nephew and I enjoyed very exhilarating, spiritual experiences, but we were lacking knowledge in how to get the most spiritual benefit out of the bath (as well as the philosophical aspects to this). The question below deals with men bathing, if the answer is different for men and women.

I understand that there are 2 ways my question can be answered:
a.  The traditional rules based on Jewish Law/Halacha
b.  The Kabbalistic answer--in terms of spiritual experience and philosophy

If possible, please answer this question with respect to the Kabbalistic interpretation.

When one goes into the Mikvah and "dunks" under, are there a certain number of times that are more auspicious to submerge oneself during the bath?

If there is a more auspicious number, what is that and why?

Thank you for your wisdom on this matter!

Comment: 310 or 9 or 4 or 3 or 1

Comment: Thanks.... 310 is quite a lot of dunks! ...tell me, is there a meaning behind these numbers?

Comment: 310 see http://www.briskodesh.org/pages/tikkunim/shay-tivilos-mikvah.htm but I think there is a earlier kabolistik source then Rabbi Nachman

Comment: 4 is for each letter of the Tetragrammaton

(We do it after staying up all night on shevuois) 3 I just found on this website regarding woman http://mikve.net/content.asp?pageid=149 is becouse this it the number of times the word mikva is written in the torah, they also bring the number 7